# Selecting one checkbox deselects other options in tkinter

Tags: python, select, tkinter, deselect

I have an LED panel with UV, Green, and Blue.  Trying to figure out how once I click "No Light" (option 4) how it would disable or deselect the first three checkbuttons (uv, green, blue)?  I saw different options here:

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_checkbutton.htm

but I don't know how to connect them.  Any thoughts would really help since I'm pretty new to Python/coding.  Appreciate any insights.  Thank you!

```
checkvar1 = tk.IntVar()
checkvar2 = tk.IntVar()
checkvar3 = tk.IntVar()
checkvar4 = tk.IntVar()

c1 = tk.Checkbutton(leftframeobjcol, text="UV", variable = checkvar1)
c1.pack(anchor="w")
c2 = tk.Checkbutton(leftframeobjcol, text="Green", variable = checkvar2)
c2.pack(anchor="w")
c3 = tk.Checkbutton(leftframeobjcol, text="Blue", variable = checkvar3)
c3.pack(anchor="w")
c4 = tk.Checkbutton(leftframeobjcol, text="No light", variable = checkvar4)
c4.pack(anchor="w")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assign a callback using `command` option for the four `Checkbutton` and in the callback, reset the other three checkbuttons or reset the `No light` checkbutton based on the passed value of the callback and the current states of the checkbuttons:

```
def reset(flag=False):
  if flag:
    # 'No light' clicked
    if checkvar4.get():
      checkvar1.set(0)
      checkvar2.set(0)
      checkvar3.set(0)
  else:
    # other light clicked, reset 'No light' if any one of the others is checked
    checkvar4.set(0 if checkvar1.get() or checkvar2.get() or checkvar3.get() else 1)


c1 = tk.Checkbutton(leftframeobjcol, text="UV", variable=checkvar1, command=reset)
c1.pack(anchor="w")
c2 = tk.Checkbutton(leftframeobjcol, text="Green", variable=checkvar2, command=reset)
c2.pack(anchor="w")
c3 = tk.Checkbutton(leftframeobjcol, text="Blue", variable=checkvar3, command=reset)
c3.pack(anchor="w")
c4 = tk.Checkbutton(leftframeobjcol, text="No light", variable = checkvar4, command=lambda:reset(True))
c4.pack(anchor="w")
```

Comment: I'd change the default value for the argument to `flag=False`, then you would only need to use `lambda` for specifying the last `Checkbutton`'s `command`. In other words, make the default value the one you want it to be most of the time.